# Time complexity of a nested loop which goes from 0 to a max/min value

Tags: time-complexity

I'm having a hard time trying to find something similar to my situation.

The pseudo-code:

```
int n = some pre-defined value
int d = some pre-defined value (that is at max the same as n, don't know if that's relevant)

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Min(i, d); j++) {
        do something
    }
}
```

I get that the first loop runs *n* times which means the time complexity itselft is O(n), but I cannot understand what is the time complexity of the second loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Computational Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity) is the amount of resources your code consumes. If your resources are given only behind a specific function f "doing-something" inside a loop, in this case, that Complexity is computed simply as the number of times the function is executed, by the resources that function consumes. That is why a nested 2D loop is said to be O(n^2): its resource consumption escalates n^2 times in order of magnitude. Hence, you should start by counting the number of loops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `d`'s max is `n`, then assume it actually is n, since big-oh notation is a worst-case upper bound.  Then you have

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        do something
    }
}
```

Since the inner loop goes from 1 to i for each value of i, then the total iterations is 1 (when i==1), + 2 (when i==2), + 3(when i == 3), and so on.  In general the total algorithm runs the inner loop body 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n times, or simplified, using the closed form, n*(n+1)/2 times.  That's effectively N-squared, since the coefficient of 1/2 can be "ignored" as it doesn't really change the shape of the graph.

You can also think of it as the length being "half n" simply because if you pair up corresponding shortest and longest runs (1 and n, 2 and (n-1), 3 and (n-2), and so on, they all average out to approx. n/2, which in big-oh notation is just n.  Looked at this way, outer loop is n, inner loop is n, so whole algorithm is O(n^2).